# LLDB does not see source files from symbols, but GDB does

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gdb, lldb

*My machine runs Ubuntu 22.04*

I've made core file like this:

```bash
$ sleep 10 & killall -SIGNEGV sleep
```

I also downloaded debug symbols for sleep via

- debuginfod (by gdb automatically)
- Ubuntu ddeb repository (and also source codes for coreutils)

When I start debugging my core file with GDB, `bt` shows me file names for sources:

```
$ gdb -q /bin/sleep -c sleep-core-dump
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...
Reading symbols from /home/gordiig/.cache/debuginfod_client/9605b84bc84dab0a28a772dcebed48b0b98ec3a9/debuginfo...
[New LWP 438331]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by 'sleep 10'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4f90fea7fa in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=req@entry=0x7ffccf5a9880, rem=rem@entry=0x7ffccf5a9870) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
#1  0x00007f4f90fef6e7 in __GI___nanosleep (req=req@entry=0x7ffccf5a9880, rem=rem@entry=0x7ffccf5a9870) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/nanosleep.c:25
#2  0x000055a5b5eb9a00 in rpl_nanosleep (remaining_delay=0x7ffccf5a9870, requested_delay=0x7ffccf5a9870) at lib/nanosleep.c:85
#3  xnanosleep (seconds=<optimized out>) at lib/xnanosleep.c:69
#4  main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>) at src/sleep.c:142
```

But when I am debugging with lldb it does not show me files, and so it doesn't show me source codes:

```
$ lldb /bin/sleep -c sleep-core-dump
(lldb) target create "/bin/sleep" --core "sleep-core-dump"
Core file '/home/gorin_d/work/playing-with-dumps/src/dumps-generator/sleep-core-dump' (x86_64) was loaded.

(lldb) target symbols add /home/gordiig/.cache/debuginfod_client/9605b84bc84dab0a28a772dcebed48b0b98ec3a9/debuginfo 
warning: (x86_64) /bin/sleep unsupported DW_FORM values: 0x1f20 0x1f21
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x55a5b5eb9b90 for breakpoint -2.1: error: elf-core does not support enabling breakpoints
symbol file '/home/gordiig/.cache/debuginfod_client/9605b84bc84dab0a28a772dcebed48b0b98ec3a9/debuginfo' has been added to '/bin/sleep'

(lldb) bt
* thread #1, name = 'sleep', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV
  * frame #0: 0x00007f4f90fea7fa libc.so.6`clock_nanosleep + 90
    frame #1: 0x00007f4f90fef6e7 libc.so.6`__nanosleep + 23
    frame #2: 0x000055a5b5eb9a00 sleep`main + 1024
    frame #3: 0x00007f4f90f2ed90 libc.so.6`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3139 + 128
    frame #4: 0x00007f4f90f2ee40 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 128
    frame #5: 0x000055a5b5eb9bb5 sleep`_start + 37

(lldb) f 2
frame #2: 0x000055a5b5eb9a00 sleep`main + 1024
sleep`main:
->  0x55a5b5eb9a00 <+1024>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x55a5b5eb9a02 <+1026>: jne    0x29d6                    ; <+982>
    0x55a5b5eb9a04 <+1028>: movq   0x58(%rsp), %rax
    0x55a5b5eb9a09 <+1033>: subq   %fs:0x28, %rax
```

If I am using debug symbols from ddebs instead of debuginfod situation becomes a bit better, but not perfect. lldb shows me names of some files, but not sleep's main file:

```
$ find-dbgsym-packages --install ./sleep-core-dump
  runs sudo apt install --no-install-recommends coreutils-dbgsym libc6-dbg
$ lldb /bin/sleep -c sleep-core-dump                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
(lldb) target create "/bin/sleep" --core "sleep-core-dump"
warning: (x86_64) /bin/sleep unsupported DW_FORM values: 0x1f20 0x1f21
Core file '/home/gordiig/work/playing-with-dumps/src/dumps-generator/sleep-core-dump' (x86_64) was loaded.

(lldb) target symbols add /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/96/05b84bc84dab0a28a772dcebed48b0b98ec3a9.debug
warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x55a5b5eb9b90 for breakpoint -2.1: error: elf-core does not support enabling breakpoints
symbol file '/usr/lib/debug/.build-id/96/05b84bc84dab0a28a772dcebed48b0b98ec3a9.debug' has been added to '/bin/sleep'

(lldb) bt
* thread #1, name = 'sleep', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV
  * frame #0: 0x00007f4f90fea7fa libc.so.6`__GI___clock_nanosleep(clock_id=0, flags=0, req=0x00007ffccf5a9880, rem=0x00007ffccf5a9870) at clock_nanosleep.c:78:7
    frame #1: 0x00007f4f90fef6e7 libc.so.6`__GI___nanosleep(req=<unavailable>, rem=<unavailable>) at nanosleep.c:25:13
    frame #2: 0x000055a5b5eb9a00 sleep`main + 1024
    frame #3: 0x00007f4f90f2ed90 libc.so.6`__libc_start_call_main(main=(sleep`main), argc=2, argv=0x00007ffccf5a99e8) at libc_start_call_main.h:58:16
    frame #4: 0x00007f4f90f2ee40 libc.so.6`__libc_start_main_impl(main=(sleep`main), argc=2, argv=0x00007ffccf5a99e8, init=(_rtld_global), fini=<unavailable>, rtld_fini=<unavailable>, stack_end=0x00007ffccf5a99d8) at libc-start.c:392:3
    frame #5: 0x000055a5b5eb9bb5 sleep`_start + 37

(lldb) f 2
frame #2: 0x000055a5b5eb9a00 sleep`main + 1024
sleep`main:
->  0x55a5b5eb9a00 <+1024>: testl  %eax, %eax
    0x55a5b5eb9a02 <+1026>: jne    0x29d6                    ; <+982>
    0x55a5b5eb9a04 <+1028>: movq   0x58(%rsp), %rax
    0x55a5b5eb9a09 <+1033>: subq   %fs:0x28, %rax
```

#### My questions are:

1. Why lldb does not see or show me source file names for some frames (especially sleep's main) while gdb does?
2. Frames from gdb and lldb don't match up. For example main frame in gdb is labeled as fourth, but in lldb it labeled as second. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

> Why lldb does not see or show me source file names for some frames

Looks to be an `lldb` bug.

> Frames from gdb and lldb don't match up.

The GDB display shows inlined functions (note that `xnanosleep` and `main` do not have a program counter attached to them).

Displaying inlined functions requires access to debug info (here debug info for the main binary), which GDB located and LLDB didn't (likely due to the bug above, which is also the reason `main` under LLDB doesn't have file/line info).

Comment: It also looks like gdb truncates the backtrace at main, which isn't really the start of that thread's stack as the lldb backtrace shows...

Comment: @JimIngham That's by design. See `set backtrace past-main`.

Comment: I assumed it was, just explaining the other difference.